# Shortest sublist including the element N with a total > MIN

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sublist

Example:

Given a list of random numbers `[1,5,1,1,3,10,5,4,2,1]`, the test element `N=10 at index 5` and a `MIN=20`.

The shortest sublist including `10` with a `total>20` is obviously the list `[3,10,5,4]` with a `total=22` and a `size=4`.

Problem:

What is an algorithm to find such a sublist in an efficient way?

Edit:

1. There might be different sublists that satisfy the condition "shortest". `[10,5,4,2]` is as short as `[3,10,5,4]` and a valid result, too.
2. A "Sublist" in this question is a consecutive block of items of the original list. `[5,10,5,4]` is not a valid sublist (I would call it instead a subset).

Comment: How do you want to handle ties? For example, [10, 5, 4, 2] is the same length, and also has a sum > 20.

Comment: Oha! I actually did not want my example to have ties :D. Nevertheless, I only need to know the size of the list and not actually its content. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Does it matter whether the sum is minimal or not? The list with [10,5,5,4] is as short as yours and Jerry's, but has higher sum.

Comment: The sum does not matter but the order of items. `[10,5,5,4]` is not a valid sublist. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm should be O(n):

Starting with test element go add elements to the left until sum>=min. This gives a first guess on the sublist length l (starting at index i). No increase start index i of sublist of length l with each step (until you reach your test element) and with each step test if you can shorten the sublist by one (on the right, i.e. decrease length l) without becoming smaller than min.

Take care of edge-cases: sum to the left is not big enough or total sum is not big enough.

Comment: (Why they are deleting their answers?) I already came to your approach on my own. I found it too much complicated so I started this question.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the shortest sublist > MAX is the same as finding the shortest sublist <= MAX where the total of the sublist exceeds MAX if either the item before or behind is added: With `[1,5,1,1,3,10,5,4,2,1]` and `MAX=20`, `[1,3,10]` is a sublist including the `10` but not valid since adding the next `5` gives a total of `19 < MAX`. The first valid sublist is here `[5,1,1,3,10]`.

The algorithm:

1. Create a `marker` for the length of the shortest sublist found.
2. Create the cursors `left` and `right`.
3. Set both cursors to `N`.
4. Move `left` to the left `while total(at left, ..., at N) <= MAX` or `left = 0`.

   1. If `left > 0` store `n - left + 1` in `marker`. Goto 6.
5. Move `right` to the right `while total(at left, ..., at right) <= MAX` or `right = list.size - 1`.

   1. If `right < list.size - 1` store `right - left + 1` in `marker`.
   2. Else: Return `list.size`.
6. Loop `while left < N and right < list.size - 1`:

   1. Move `left` by one to the right.
   2. Test the item `at right + 1`, if any.

      1. If `total + at right + 1 > MAX` store `right - left + 1` in `marker`.
      2. Else move right by one the the right.

I'll give Howard the answer, anyway.